# How to notify an activity that another activity is finished

Tags: android

This is probably a newbie question.  How do you make sure a function in Activity A is called when Activity B finishes?  I can't put the code where Activity B finishes, so I am wondering if there is a way to do this.  I looked for a solution and found broadcasting but I don't know how to do that.  Does anyone know of a simple solution to this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Use `startActivitityForResult` `onActivityResult` pair.

ActivityA:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

ActivityB:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("result",result);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);     
 finish();
```

ActivityA:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // here AcivityB is finished. Call your method

}
```

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing. This is how to do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: what if ActivityA it's a RecyclerView?